# Need tips on hard surface curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

im working on pot of greed from Yu Gi Oh. I have modeled the base mesh and was wondering if anyone has any tips on doing these curved  lines highlighted in the image below.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Bezier curve, project its vertices on the surface using the face snapping option (as you grab a vertex, it will be projected onto the nearest face, according to the view), then create another curve to set the profile of the line (choose it as Bevel object).

[image]

In Blender 4.1:

[image]

Comment: what's the 'BezierCurve profile' for? Is it duplicate of 'BezierCurve'?

Comment: It's another curve object (generally a "Cyclic" one) that you can use to model the shape of the cavity that surrounds the main curve: the most common is a circle, that creates a long curved cylinder, but you can assign to this profile any shape you want. See updated for 4.1 answer.